# Efficiently sending player movement over network

Tags: java, networking

I'm making a Java game using Slick2D, and using Kryonet for multiplayer.  When a player pressing W, A, S, or D, they move, and a PlayerMovePacket object is sent across the network (via UDP) to the server.  The server then sends this to the other clients, which set their local copy of that player's position according to the information inside the packet.

Here's the code for PlayerMovePacket:

```
public class PlayerMovePacket {

public Vector2f pos;
public int clientID;

public PlayerMovePacket() {
    pos = new Vector2f(0, 0);
    clientID = -1;
}

public PlayerMovePacket(Vector2f v, int id) {
    pos = v;
    clientID = id;
}
}
```

Doing this, the clients/server get overloaded from too many messages, and crash.  The only other option I see is that I would only send the player's position every couple milliseconds.  However, clients would not have the latest position of the player most of the time, and movement would be jumpy

Any ideas on how I could stop the server from being overloaded?

Comment: If every single move is important do not use UDP since it may not reach endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a threshold, is it really critical that you send movement data for every little move?

Another approach is to aggregate it every couple of milliseconds as suggested. If the player moved 3 times (or 3 actions) you can aggregate that movemement into one packet and save yourself some network I/O. It really depends on the game though and what your consistency guarantees are. In most cases sending data every 25-50ms is acceptable as you cannot perceive changes any quicker anyway.

@jussi mentioned also that you can try and predict movement on the client side and simply compensate every time a new player position packet is received which is also acceptable and used quite widely. I would caution trying to make it very complex as it can make the game even more jumpy or laggy but simple straight line trajectories will work just fine. You can see examples of this in many games where you see people that disconnect sometimes run in place or run into objects in the game until the server recognizes that they have actually disconnected and such things are acceptable as you need high enough thresholds that lag spikes will not cause complete server disconnects on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could send the positions every couple milliseconds and do some sort of client side prediction in order to make it less jumpy.

Comment: +1 for client side prediction, although if implemented wrong it can make it even more jumpy.

Comment: This is quite normal. Think about playing video games with lag. When you start to fall behind with high latency and you "lag", your character will normally continue  their current path/trajectory/speed until the server updates at which point you are thrown back into the correct location. But the client or local console game will normally continue to predict where you're headed based on your recent movement.

Comment: @Kyle Yeah that's why I mentioned that done wrong it can be quite laggy looking (especially in some games where lag compensation makes the game much harder to play *cough* call of duty *cough*).